# Link with unencrypted protocol inspection, WebStorm security warning?

Tags: html, typescript, security, svg, webstorm

In my React TypeScript project I have used some **.svg** icons which works absolutely fine but on  **Inspect Code** in **WebStorm** IDE it's showing weak warnings and I have to resolve all the warnings (Not Suppress).

> **Link with unencrypted protocol inspection**
> Opening links with unencrypted protocols (such as HTTP) can expose your data to man-in-the-middle attacks, which are dangerous in general and may be especially harmful for artifact repositories. Use protocols with encryption, such as HTTPS. For more information, [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS#Difference_from_HTTP)

I have already tried to search fix for this issue but wasn't able to find something relevant, I would appreciate it if someone can suggest what will be the best approach to resolve the issue.

**Read :** [Does svg xmlns attribute value requires protocol? Can it be https or relative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39960017/does-svg-xmlns-attribute-value-requires-protocol-can-it-be-https-or-relative)

SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><defs><style>.a{fill:#0d0d0d;}.b{clip-path:url(#a);}.c{fill:#fff;}.d{filter:url(#b);}</style><clipPath id="a"><rect class="a" width="24" height="24" transform="translate(0.187 0.375)"/></clipPath><filter id="b" x="-14.937" y="-11.875" width="52.893" height="47.468" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><feOffset input="SourceAlpha"/><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="6" result="c"/><feFlood flood-color="#0670eb"/><feComposite operator="in" in2="c"/><feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/></filter></defs><g class="b" transform="translate(-0.187 -0.375)"><g transform="translate(3.25 6.5)"><g class="d" transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -3.06, -6.13)"><path class="c" d="M11.039,17.951a1.2,1.2,0,0,1-.922-.4L5.2,12.506a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.888-1.8l4,4.128L19.515,6.84a1.3,1.3,0,0,1,1.8,1.888L11.961,17.6A1.51,1.51,0,0,1,11.039,17.951Z" transform="translate(-1.76 -0.36)"/></g></g></g></svg>
```

**SVG**
[image: SVG]

**Warnings**
[image: Warning]

[image: Warning]

Comment: Report it as a bug in webstorm then. That's not a protocol, it's a namespace. That a namespace resembles a protocol is coincidence. A hover fly resembles a wasp, that doesn't make it a wasp.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the reply, will try to report it on WebStorm :)

Answer (score 1):

Please feel free to vote for [IDEA-265304](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265304) to be notified on any progress with it.

Note that `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` URL is added to **Ignored URLs** in **Security | Link with unencrypted protocol** inspection options by default

Comment: thanks for the reply, hope to see getting this issue fixed ASAP...